# Django deploy Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

The site work fine on my localhost, but I have problems deploying It.

[log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S11yZ.png)

[log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQNT9.png)

[VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDRZO.png)

[PA files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypd5y.png)

[WSGI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg6D0.png)

Comment: please copy paste source code directly into your question.

Otherwise search engines and the builtin Stackoverflow search cannot work, which will make your question very uninteresting for future users.

One of the goals of stack overflow is, that good questions and answers can be found by others. in order to avoid asking the same (or similar) questions over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` has to be in Python path syntax, e.g. `"Insertemp.settings"`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

Comment: Thank mate. But still does not work, mabye something else is wrong. I gues when I got it up and running on my computer, I just follow the docs on pythonanywhere.com to get it launched. Does It matter if I do not have a database? On my computer I use XAMPP without a django database. Does the site run without a database? Best regard RIJ

Comment: It's hard to tell more with the data from your original question. You can run Django without the db but why use a Django at all in that case?

Comment: @Remiingemann Can you paste the most recent error message from the error log? (You provided screenshots for wsgi file twice)

Comment: @Filip, I'm gonna use a DB, but just wanted to deploy the site first to see if It was working (I just started programming, so babysteps for me at this point :-) ) **caseneuve, hehe Yes I see that now. I'm adding a couple of new img as well. Thanks a lot for the help. PS! I've tried with the setting: 'Insert.settings as well, but did not work for me.

Comment: @Filip , I had a good nights sleep and found the problem. I was as simpel as a extra folder in my path. So just removed it, and it work. Thanx for the help. Have a greath weekend!